# Retrieving the value of each input box jquery. Is there a better way then using get()?

Tags: jquery

I'm just not familiar with the get() method and was wondering if there was a simpler way to retrieve all the values of a form's input boxes located in a section. This is what I have and it works:

Form logic:

```
function submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var addresses = $('.add_address_section .add_address_field').map(function() { return $(this).val() }).get();
    ...
```

The above works, but I'm wondering why I need the get(). Shouldn't val() bet getting me the value of the input box?

Without the get, this is what returns:

```
$('.add_address_section .add_address_field').map(function() { return $(this).val() })
w.fn.init(2) ["12323", "515", prevObject: w.fn.init(2)]
```

What is the above object?

FYI, this is my html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Greeting Page</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="add_coins.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/add_coins.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="grumpy_cat.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="coin-form-wrapper">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is my jquery:

```
$(function(){
  var coinFormWrapper = $(".coin-form-wrapper");
  var submitAddressButton = $('.add_address_button');
  var inputHTML = `
    <div class='address_field'>
      <input type='text' class='add_address_field' name='field_name[]' value=""/>
      <input type='button' class='remove_address_button' value='Remove Address'/>
    </div>
  `;
  var addAddressButton = `
    <div class='add_address'>
      <input type='button' class='add_address_button' value='Add Another Address'/>
    </div>
  `
  var submitButton = `
    <div class='submit_address'>
      <input type='button' class='submit_button' value='Mix Addresses'/>
    </div>
  `
  var addAddressHTML = `
    <div class='add_address_section'>
    </div>
  `

  addAddAddressButton()
  // there should be 1 field at intiial page load
  addAddAddressHTML()
  addInputField()
  addSubmitButton()

  // =========listeners============
  $(coinFormWrapper).on('click', '.remove_address_button', function(e) {
    removeInputRow.call(this)
  });

  $(coinFormWrapper).on('click', '.add_address_button', function(e) {
    addInputField()
  });

  $(coinFormWrapper).on('click', '.submit_button', function(e) {
    submitForm(e)
  });


  // reuseable functions
  function addInputField() {
    $('.add_address_section').append(inputHTML);
  }

  function addAddAddressButton() {
    $(coinFormWrapper).append(addAddressButton);
  }

  function addAddAddressHTML() {
    $(coinFormWrapper).append(addAddressHTML)
  }

  function removeInputRow(e) {
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
  }

  function addSubmitButton() {
    $(coinFormWrapper).append(submitButton);
  }

  function submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var addresses = $('.add_address_section .add_address_field').map(function() { return $(this).val() }).get();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/mix_addresses',
      //grab the inputs from address_section
      data: { 'addresses': addresses },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        debugger;
        //if our ajax request is successful, replace the content of our viz div with the response data
        $('#viz').html(data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: `.get()` is used to get the object's array values. This is explained in the documentation: *"As the return value is a jQuery object, which contains an array, it's very common to call .get() on the result to work with a basic array."* - http://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: Is there a better way?

Comment: For the purpose of getting an array of values, no. If you're submitting a form [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) might be useful